# OnInitializedAsync On navigationchanged

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

In a Blazor ASP.NET Core 8 solution we have a RazorControl which changes content based on the url.

We have the following scenarios :

1. /planter/
2. /kvaeg/
3. /machines/
4. /business/

Our `OnInitializedAsync` is like below and it selects some articles and renders the page.

Our problem is that due to Blazor life cycle events, the `OnInitializedAsync` is only fired on the first visit.

We have used `OnNavigationChanged`, but that gave us some other issues. I  don't think `OnParametersSetAsync` is an option.

Is there any other solution to ensure that `OnInitializedAsync` is fired on navigationchanged?

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
    Uri uri = new(NavigationManager.Uri);

    int dataSourceID = 0;

    switch (uri.Segments[1].ToLower())
    {
        case "planter":
            dataSourceID = 1068;
            break;
        case "kvaeg":
            dataSourceID = 1067;
            break;
        case "maskiner":
            dataSourceID = 1069;
            break;
        case "business":
            dataSourceID = 1142;
            break;
    }

    DocumentFilter documentFilter = new() 
    { 
        DataSourceID = dataSourceID, 
        WebSiteID = 16, 
        ShowInFeed = true, 
        ForceDataSourceUpdate = false 
    };

    ResponseDTO<IReadOnlyCollection<DocumentListDTO>> responseDTO = await 
   DocumentCacheService.GetDocumentsAsync($"DataSource{dataSourceID}", documentFilter);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to respond to a parameter, so OnParametersSet() is the more logical choice than OnInitialized(). OnInitialized only runs once.

OnParametersSet() doesn't fire when it doesn't have to. You can use a trick to control this, add

```
[SupplyParameterFromQuery]
public int DummyNeverUsed { get; set; }
```

No need to add anything to the @page lines.

Now OnParametersSetAsync() will execute every time you change te URL.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to handle this using parameters to capture the *DataSource* name, but you haven't show enough code to see your full intent.

Based on the code you've provided, you should be able to do something like this using `OnParametersSetAsync`.  It checks the state of `dataSourceID` and only updates `responseDTO` when the state changes.

```cs
private int _dataSourceID; 

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
 {
    var dataSourceStateChanged = this.CheckIfDataSourceStateHasChanged()

    If(!dataSourceStateChanged)
        return;
    
    DocumentFilter documentFilter = new() 
    { 
        DataSourceID = dataSourceID, 
        WebSiteID = 16, 
        ShowInFeed = true, 
        ForceDataSourceUpdate = false 
    };

    ResponseDTO<IReadOnlyCollection<DocumentListDTO>> responseDTO = await DocumentCacheService.GetDocumentsAsync($"DataSource{dataSourceID}", documentFilter);

    //....
}

private bool CheckIfDataSourceStateHasChanged()
{
    Uri uri = new(NavigationManager.Uri);

    int dataSourceID = 0;

    switch (uri.Segments[1].ToLower())
    {
        case "planter":
            dataSourceID = 1068;
            break;
        case "kvaeg":
            dataSourceID = 1067;
            break;
        case "maskiner":
            dataSourceID = 1069;
            break;
        case "business":
            dataSourceID = 1142;
            break;
    }

    var changed = _datSourceID != dataSourceID

    if (changed)
        _datasourceID = dataSourceID;

    return changed;
```